# Order dice rolls in the game of Risk

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Last evening I was playing the game of Risk with some friends, and this question came to my mind:

> Can one order all the possible dice rolls of the attacker
>   (from the best one to the worst one) just by looking at the sum of the
>   3 dices?

I hope the question is clear. To clarify, surely one can say that $(6,6,6)$ is a better roll than $(3,3,3)$. This agrees with the fact that $6+6+6=18 > 3+3+3 = 9$.

But what about $(2,2,4)$ and $(1,2,5)$ ? They both sum to $8$, but are they equivalent?

Intuitively, I would say that the answer to my above question is **"No, it's not possible to order them just by looking at their sum"**. However, I was not able to prove this fact mathematically. Do you have any clue about this?

Comment: I guess the answer is as simple as the counter-example that you gave. Both $(2,2,4)$ and $(1,2,5)$ sum to $8$, yet the second roll is better than the first. So, no, it is not possible to order all rolls by looking at the sum.

Comment: Or with $(6,6,1)$ and $(5,5,5)$, the first triple is strictly better than the second (relative to the game of Risk), but with the first sum being strictly less than the second.

Comment: You can order it, equivalent or not, because you can create a criteria to do it. But I dont know the rules of Risk or what you can make with a order.

Answer (score 1):

You've already done so with that counterexample, I think. The claim would be

> All rolls of equal total are equivalent. That is, they have the same outcome against all defending rolls.

But your counterexample shows that this is not the case as $ ( 1, 2, 5 ) $ has the outcome of two defender casualties against the defending roll $ ( 1, 4 ), $ whereas the roll $ ( 2 , 2 , 4) $ has the outcome of one attacker casualty and one defender casualty against the same defending roll.